# GitHub Actions - To pull the latest commits and display the file names which are checked-in in the respective folders

Tags: github-actions

Not able to pull the latest commits whenever the user saves the transaction in the respective folders in the GitHub repo. We require to pull the latest changes which are happened to the current user whenever he triggers the pipeline and find out which files are the latest commit. We require this file info because we will take these file names and store them in the AWS EFS file system through EC2 machine.

```yaml
 - name: Get Commit Details
        run: |
          commit_sha="${{ github.event.after }}"
          response=$(curl -sSL \
            -H "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" \
            -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
            "https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/commits/$commit_sha")
            echo "$response" > commit.json
    
      - name: Extract File Names
        run: |
          # updated_files=$(jq -r '.files[].filename' commit.json)
          # echo "$updated_files" > updated_files.txt
          echo $(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --patch-with-raw -r HEAD)
```

Some of the examples which we worked but nothing clicked so far.